# Oracle ODBC TNS-less connection string (for 64-bit Excel)

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc, connection-string, tnsnames

Is there a 64-bit Oracle ODBC driver that supports TNS-less connection (or EZ-Connect) convention? I used to use "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" which allowed a TNS-less connection string, but that has been depreciated for a long time and there is no 64-bit version (i.e. it won't work for 64-bit Office/Excel).

I've had the experience that user's in my organization sometimes have a missing or invalid tnsnames.ora file. I want to use a DSN-less connection-string in that does **not** require tnsnames.ora that can be successfully executed on any computer with the proper Oracle drivers installed. This is an example of my old DSN-less, TNS-less connection string that used the depreciated "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" driver (still works for users on 32-bit office):

```
DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; UID=myun; PWD=mypass;
SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
       (HOST=myhostname)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mysid)));
```

---

I have been trying to connect with **Oracle in OraClient11g_home1** ODBC drivers from Oracle but no matter how I try (including EZ_Connect) I can not get it to work without it needing tnsnames.ora, I constantly get this pop-up asking me to specify a service name anyway:

[image]

I have tried using EZ-Connect and many other variations of specifying the Oracle server IP/hostname directly like below but have had no luck:

```
Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};Server=//OracleIPAddress:1521/MySID;
Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the service name you can simply insert the whole TNS-String, e.g. `SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhostname)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mysid)));`

Enclose it by double quotes and remove any carriage-returns and space charaters.

Comment: Would every end-user need to do that everytime or will doing it once cause it to save the details into the excel file?

Comment: I assume it should save it